# How to return a multidimensional array keys as a tree?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, treeview, php-5.3

I am working on an MLM application in which i need to show all users as a tree. For this is implemented parent child relationship among the users. my table structure is here :-

[image]

I had retrieve the id's of users in a multidimensional array as per the relation. Here is array:-

[image]

For this i used this code :-

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('testapp', $con);

function create_tree( $parent_id = 0 )
{
    $result_array = array();
    $Query = 'SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `parent`=\''.$parent_id.'\';';
    $query_result = mysql_query($Query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($query_result)>0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
        {
            if(!array_key_exists($row['user_id'], $result_array))
            {
                //$result_array[$row['user_id']] = $row;
                $result_array[$row['user_id']] = create_tree($row['user_id']);
            }
        }
    }
    return $result_array;
}
$tree = create_tree();
print_r($tree);
```

Now, i need to show the data in a tree structure like :-
[image]

Any hint will be helpful. I am very near to complete this...

Comment: Hint: Use BST Logic ,wrt parent and child relation ship.

Comment: if you use codeigniter, why don't you use db driver?

Comment: @rcpayan This work is done using PHP only without any framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are so near..!!

**Try below it will be work for you..**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('testapp', $con);

function create_tree( $parent_id = 0 ,$result_array = array())
{

$Query = 'SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `parent`=\''.$parent_id.'\';';
$query_result = mysql_query($Query);
if(mysql_num_rows($query_result)>0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
    {
        if(!array_key_exists($row['user_id'], $result_array))
        {
            //$result_array[$row['user_id']] = $row;
            $result_array[$row['user_id']] = create_tree($row['user_id'],$result_array);
        }
    }
}
return $result_array;
}
$tree = create_tree();
print_r($tree);
?>
```

If this will not work for you than let me know..!!

Thanks..

Comment: Ok, i will make one demo for this and check

Answer (score 0):

try that, it should give you the structure;

```
function create_tree( $parent_id = 0 , $result_array = array() )
{
    //$result_array = array();
    $Query = 'SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `parent`=\''.$parent_id.'\';';
    $query_result = mysql_query($Query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($query_result)>0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
        {
            if(!array_key_exists($row['user_id'], $result_array))
            {
                //$result_array[$row['user_id']] = $row;
                $result_array[$row['user_id']] = create_tree($row['user_id'], $result_array[$row['user_id']]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $result_array;
}
```

edit; forgot the remove result_array in function